# Flutter: XCode error "Unable to boot the Simulator"

Tags: xcode, flutter

I am running the latest OSX/Flutter/XCode Versions using flutter, android studio and firebase. One hour ago, everything was working perfectly.

Then I rebooted my macbook and when I tried to launch an ios simulator; I got this error: "Unable to boot the simulator".

The following steps didn't fix it:

1. Reinstall the ios simulator
2. Flutter clean and pub get
3. Updating comand line tools 13.3.1 (13E500a)
4. Run invalid cache of android studio

How can I fix this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72658637/5780058

Comment: @NicklasF Reopening multiiple times doesn't actually fix it.  Just waiting a few minutes fixes it.  See my answer below with more specifics about what is going on.  TLDR: Wait for syspolicyd process to quiesce which should indicate the scan is complete, and you can retry.

Comment: @JeremyHuddlestonSequoia Ah cool. Makes sense. I delete my comment to avoid confusion.

Answer (score -6, accepted):

### NO NEED TO UNINSTALL XCODE!

##### On macOS 13 and above:

Go to `System Settings` → `General` → `Storage` → `Developer`

Delete "Developer Caches"

##### On macOS 12 and below

Go to `About this Mac` → `Storage` → `Manage` → `Developer`

Delete all the content

> Don't worry on deleting all content, there is no data loss.

---

> Note that you also do not need to select the "Command Line Tools" for deletion for this solution to work

Comment: Thank you it took a while, but it works now!

Answer (score 857):

### *NO NEED TO UNINSTALL XCODE!*

#### On macOS 13 and above

1. Go to **System Settings → General → Storage → Developer**
2. Delete "Developer Caches"

#### On macOS 12 and below

1. Go to **About this Mac → Storage → Manage → Developer**
2. Delete all the content (no worries!)

Comment: This solution worked for me first time. Next day not worked. I am using flutter. So i built the app from xcode and issue fixed

Comment: If you're on MacOS >= 13.0 and "About this Mac" doesn't have a "Storage" tab, [skip to this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74409402/568458)

Comment: so, run project from direct xCode, it will open simulator automatically

Comment: Just clearing the developer caches did the job

Comment: Anyone running macOS Sonoma 14.0, "About this Mac" > "More info..." >Developer (info icon) > Select anything that has "xcode" and "cache" in it > Click "Delete". Close all this and relaunch simulator.

Comment: I'd like to make an amendment to @pragmateek answer for users running Sonoma 14.0.

Click on the Apple icon (top left) > "About this Mac" > "More info..." > "Storage Settings" > Developer (click info icon) > Select anything that has "xcode" and "cache" in it > Click "Delete".

The developer info icon is in "Storage Settings"

Comment: Maybe a better way to write the step 1 could be “Search for ’Storage’ in the Spotlight > Developer” cuz it opens right away the storage tab.

Comment: Curious as to the cause of this.  The heavily voted down answer hints at the cause but "somehow" isn't a good explanation.  It appears this is recurring and would be better if there was a way to reliably reproduce it so we could point Apple, Google, et. al. to a fix.

Comment: Note that you also do not need to select the "Command Line Tools" for deletion for this solution to work

Comment: Worked like wonders, very helpful @Damia

Comment: Thanks so much, this worked on MacBook Pro (14.3.1 )

Answer (score 306):

For Mac Ventura 13.0 OS and higher -> Click apple logo on top left of your Mac

```
System Settings > search Storage > Developer
```

Then delete Xcode Caches

[image]

Comment: But here I have deleted both `Project Build Data and Indexes` and `Xcode Caches` also. will this create any problem?

Comment: After you delete `Xcode Caches` you can run `open -a Simulator` from terminal to boot up Simulator

Comment: It removed 9 GB of the useless data and now it works fine. Thanks!

Comment: Sometimes good ol' StackOverflow easily solves stuff ChatGPT can't.

Comment: This is the way as of Xcode 15.3.

Answer (score 176):

**Step 1:**
Go to **About this Mac**

[image]

**Step 2:**
Go to **Storage**
[image]

**Step 3:**
Delete all the content Or Delete **XCode Cache**

[image]

Answer (score 172):

For those who like to do it through the terminal.

1. Close the simulator.
2. In the terminal, run:

```
rm -R ~/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Caches
```

Or run with sudo, if it says that access denied:

```
sudo rm -R ~/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Caches
```

3. Restart the simulator.

Comment: This solved the issue but there was no need for sudo.

Comment: This is the right answer and should be accepted. Others are about deleting development files which poses more risk of reinstalling and setting up xcode.

Comment: This is the right answer since it doesn't make you clean-up you whole environment

Comment: This only temporarilary resolves the issue, but it will return after the cache is recreated and before GateKeeper scanning completes.  You're better off just waiting a few minutes.  See my answer below for more specifics.

Comment: I found myself having to execute this command very often. utilizing ZSH we can use a method that can be run in the terminal without hassle and on demand.

add this to your .zprofile: 
```sh

simulator_cache() {
  rm -R ~/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Caches
}

```
and run simulator_cache in your terminal when needed.

Answer (score 87):

You can delete xcode cache and it will work,

by going to

About this Mac > Storage > Manage > Developer or any folder you choosed for development when installing xcode and flutter then Delete XCode Cache.

Answer (score 42):

You can just **clean your Xcode Caches**, and that will do the trick,

1. About this Mac
2. Storage
3. Developer
4. **XCode Caches**

Answer (score 27):

Got this issue on MacBook Air M2, 2022 and solve it by the following.

Go to `System Settings --> General --> Storage --> Developer` then clear the `Xcode Cache`.

Comment: Work also on Intel (MacBook Pro 2019 16')

Comment: This only temporarilary resolves the issue, but it will return after the cache is recreated and before GateKeeper scanning completes.  You're better off just waiting a few minutes.  See my answer below for more specifics.

Answer (score 21):

1. Close all running iOS simulators: `sudo killall Simulator`
2. Clear iOS simulator cache: `rm -rf ~/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Caches`
3. Start iOS simulator

Comment: This only temporarilary resolves the issue, but it will return after the cache is recreated and before GateKeeper scanning completes.  You're better off just waiting a few minutes.  See my answer below for more specifics.

Answer (score 19):

This worked for me.

Cleared the cache of the Developer Simulators -

```
rm -R ~/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Caches
```

Will post more ways if i found something.

Comment: This only temporarilary resolves the issue, but it will return after the cache is recreated and before GateKeeper scanning completes.  You're better off just waiting a few minutes.  See my answer below for more specifics.

Answer (score 12):

This method works for me
You can just clean your Xcode Caches, and that will do the trick,
Go To About this Mac -> Storage -> Developer -> XCode Caches

Comment: This is a duplicate answer. Numerous other users have recommended this exact remedy, and this answer does not add anything substantive. Please only post answers when they contribute new content.

Answer (score 9):

For me it was not necessary to delete XCode. I could solve it with this:

1: Click on "About this Mac" in the top left corner

2: Click on "Storage"-Tab

3: Click on "Manage"-Button

4: Click on "Developer"-Tab

5: Right click on all the data and "Delete"

Answer (score 8):

I could fix that problem simply clearing the cache:

```
rm -rf ~/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Caches
```

Comment: This only temporarilary resolves the issue, but it will return after the cache is recreated and before GateKeeper scanning completes.  You're better off just waiting a few minutes.  See my answer below for more specifics.

Answer (score 7):

Simple steps:
You can just clean your Xcode Caches, and that will do the trick

1. Open "About this Mac" from the Apple menu.
2. Go to the "Storage" tab and click on 'manage'.
3. Look for the "Developer" folder and open it.
4. Inside the "Developer" folder, locate the "Xcode Caches" directory.
5. Delete the contents of the "Xcode Caches" folder.
6. Once the caches are cleared, try opening the Simulator again.

By following these steps, you can resolve certain issues related to the Simulator in Xcode

Answer (score 6):

Got this issue in M1 MB Air in 2023 Solved it by,

Settings > Storage > Developer > Clear Xcode Cache.

Answer (score 4):

Deleting caches should not be necessary here.  I expect that will just cause the issue to recur later.

There are a few causes we've identified for this issue:

1. There is a performance issue reading from the simulator runtime disk images which can result in boot triggering that watchdog timer, especially if I/O is competing with the process that is generating the dyld shared cache. This performance issue has been addressed in macOS 14.4 Beta and later.
2. The dyld_sim shared cache fails to map into a process within the watchdog timer because it was just recently created and is still being scanned by the system.  Deleting the cache will momentarily address this problem, but you would hit it again the next time the cache is created.  Waiting ~2 minutes should allow the scan to complete.  Additionally, if you update to Xcode 15.3 Beta 2 or later (released last week), we now avoid attempting to use the cache until that scan is complete.
3. If an XProtect update is installed (which happens ~weekly), that will invalidate the cached scan results for the dyld shared cache, and you will hit the issue on subsequent boots.  As of the currnet version of Xcode (15.3), there is no workaround for this, but we hope to deliver one soon.

I recommend that users facing this issue please update to macOS 14.4 Beta or later and Xcode 15.3 Beta 2 or later to get the mitigations that are available.

If you still see this issue, please collect the following tarballs and attach them to a report at http://bugreport.apple.com:

```
xcrun simctl diagnose
sudo sysdiagnose
```

Also, if you're able, please enable debug logging via:

```
defaults write com.apple.CoreSimulator DebugLogging -bool YES
```

You can remove the debug logging later with:

```
defaults delete com.apple.CoreSimulator DebugLogging)
```

Note that we've had multiple reports of this issue over the past 6 months, but triage has been difficult in part because we have not been getting the logging requested above and by the time the reporter gets around to responding to the request, they are out of the problematic state (because it usually resolves on its own in a few minutes).  Please do not assume that someone else is providing the data. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Settings -> General -> Storage--> Developer--> Delete the Xcode Caches

Answer (score 2):

For me, it works by removing these folders and restarting the simulator.

Run this command on your terminal:

> run  `rm -R ~/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Caches`

> run `rm -R ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/iOS\ DeviceSupport/`

> run `rm -R ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/`

Comment: Only needed the first one thanks, and did it via Finder to be safe

Comment: Yes, it works. I just think it would be easier to use Terminal.

Answer (score 1):

Product-> Clean Build Folder works for me!

Answer (score 1):

install "DevCleaner for xcode" from app store then choose option delete old Simulator & Device Logs after this it work

Answer (score 1):

if you are running MacOS: Sonoma 14.2.1
DO this:

1. Click on the Apple icon at the top left of the screen
2. Click on "About this Mac"
3. Click on "More info..."
4. Scroll down to "Storage" you'd see the name of your Mac, click on "storage settings..."
5. Scroll down to "Developer" then click on the "Help icon" at the right end
6. Select on "Xcode caches"
7. Click on "Delete"
8. Click on "Done"
9. Go back to Xcode and run it again.

It worked for me

Answer (score 1):

I tried all the above issues like deleting the `XCode Cache`. However, I was not able to launch the simulator. What helped me:

1. I checked the simulator in `Force Quit Tab` by clicking the Apple icon in the top left.
2. I forced quit this.
3. I closed my `vs code`. Then opened the vs code again, and launched the simulator. It opened.

Answer (score 0):

**For me it worked after opening XCode and installing ios.**

1. Start XCode
2. Open a project or create one
3. At the Top you find the 'Runner', and the words 'Any IOS Device'. Click on the second
4. Manage Run Destinations
5. Simulators
6. Push the '+'
7. 'OS Version: Download more simulator runtimes'
8. find iOS and click on 'GET'

Answer (score 0):

In my case changing the Runner Scheme in Xcode back to `Build Configuration` -> `Debug` and `Build executable` -> `Check the box` worked. Every time I build my app on a physical device I leave this on Release and without a checked box and the simulator is not booting until returning to default setting there.

Answer (score 0):

Uninstall Xcode and restart the Macbook device and again install Xcode, i hope the problem will be fixed.

Answer (score 0):

After trying some of the answers here, (cleaning developer cache, updating flutter) without any success, I went to the **activity monitor** and **killed** 4 processes called **"xcdevice"**.

After that I was finally able to normally start a new xcode device.

I hope that will help someone.

Comment: Killing those processes didn't actually help the situation.  What solved it for you was just waiting a little while which allowed the system to complete the scan of the dyld shared cache.  See my answer for more specifics.

Answer (score -1):

Try:

1. open terminal
2. run `brew install fastlane`
3. run `fastlane snapshot reset_simulators`
   This will recreate your simulators, and work the majority of the time.

Answer (score -1):

Start the iOS simulator manually.

Right click on simulator and select whatever device you like, it'll automatically come to sync with flutter doctor.

Answer (score -2):

The answers with the highest scores work, I also found this alternative in case you want to try, simply right click on simulator > device > choose any device other than the one selected:

[Image with step by step](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Umpe5.png)

Comment: The reason your solution works is just because of the time delay.  See my answer for more specifics.