# The operation couldn’t be completed. (AppThinning.StubError error 1.)

Tags: ios, xcode

After updating Xcode 14.0 when I try to distribute application as adhoc or developer, from the Xcode organizer I get the Error like

"The operation couldn’t be completed. (AppThinning.StubError error 1.)"
[image]

But when I select upload application on the app store or try to export app for the app store its working fine and upload app on the app store.

Please suggest me what the issue this and if any know the solution then please guide.

Comment: I think Apple is having issues with this as a whole. I'm having the exact opposite problem as you (able to export an ad hoc build but unable to get through "processing" when uploading to the App Store). After a couple weeks of emailing and calling them, they said their developers are "working on this issue". They are incredibly unhelpful, and I think we can really only wait till they fix this issue...

Comment: However, maybe your issue is separate from mine. They gave me this link to debug app thinning issues which might help you: https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/technotes/tn2432/_index.html

Comment: I worked around it by switching from automatically managed signing to manual creation & selection of a valid Provisioning Profile.

Comment: Yes, After some days its working 
Thanks for your comments guys

Comment: any solution for this because in Xcode 14.2 it is not working ?

Comment: Same for me in 14.2

Comment: I am getting in 14.3

Answer (score 23):

You can use this trick:

After press next button

[image]

[image]

[image]

before having the error:

I pressed repeatedly **Enter(Return)** button on the keyboard and It passes the error.

I could have an ad-hoc IPA

Comment: It's crazy that this acually works. I can't believe Apple, the most valuable company in the world, is unable to provide a smooth distribution.

Comment: I confirm this "works". Wonderful work, Apple

Comment: Lol, I posted comment below that installing sqlite3 helped me, but after what I installed Xcode 14.2 I was not able to past this error, until I went with this Enter spamming approach. What a joke.

Comment: this is crazy, this worked perfectly. Is a easter egg?

Comment: I was getting error in xcode 14.3 and this solution worked like magic.. thanx buddy

Answer (score 4):

In my case,
(Maybe install older version XCode 13.4.1 is not needed.)
I install older version XCode 13.4.1, and distribute application as adhoc again,
then still show "The operation couldn’t be completed. (AppThinning.StubError error 1.)", I Click Show Logs, it will open logs folder.
Open IDEDistribution.standard.log file,
then I saw the error:
`require': cannot load such file -- sqlite3/sqlite3_native (LoadError)

So I search keyword and find this article.
https://github.com/sparklemotion/sqlite3-ruby/issues/240

I try these SUDO Command:

gem uninstall sqlite3 --all

ridk exec pacman -S mingw-w64-x86_64-sqlite3

gem inst sqlite3 --platform ruby

Then distribute application as adhoc again, distribute Successful!
Now you can back to XCode 14.1, and work fine again.

Comment: Thanks! This solved my issue on Xcode 14.1, but the SQLite3 log error appears now on `IDEDistribution.verbose.log` file.

Important, you also need to restart Xcode after the gem install.

Answer (score 4):

I installed sqlite3, and set to use system default.

```
$ sudo gem install sqlite3
$ rvm use system --default
```

I referenced below.

https://blog.csdn.net/RreamigOfGirls/article/details/128146944

Answer (score 2):

I have fixed the issue by running `sudo gem install sqlite3`

You may need to restart your computer after the installation

The reason is because of this line in the `IDEDistribution.verbose.log` file

`/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:130:in require': cannot load such file -- sqlite3/sqlite3_native (LoadError)`

It may be happening because you installed another version of ruby, causing sqlite3 to be missing

More info [here](https://blog.csdn.net/RreamigOfGirls/article/details/128146944)

Comment: `sudo gem install sqlite3` helped me

Answer (score 1):

In my case, starting Xcode with Rosetta let me do the Ad-Hoc distribution

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

This was broken for me on Xcode 14.0.1 but seems to be working on Xcode 14.1. I'm not sure if it's random luck, or actually fixed, as it's not mentioned in the release notes that I could find.

Answer (score 0):

Disabling bitcode worked for me. This is probably with an internal change apple made for ad-hoc builds or an error. I hope it's the latter.

Comment: Experiencing same issue. Even with disabled bitcode. From time to time it works, but in most cases it doesn't. Very frustrating.

Comment: Having also the same issue (working in Xcode 13.4.1 but not in Xcode 14.0.1), I tried to disable bitcode but the problem persists. From some tests, I have noticed the problem doesn't happen with a new project, which makes me think is some configuration that clashing. 

Additionally any builds sent to TestFlight seems to get stuck in processing since  Xcode 14 came up.

Comment: I found some additional information in the logs: OS_at_encoder is implemented in both /usr/lib/libate.dylib and /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/usr/bin/assetutil however can't see where the "OS_at_encoder" is used

Comment: Has anyone been able to solve this yet? I disabled bitcode and still same problem. On Xcode 14.0.1

Answer (score 0):

Hi These Error may occur due to low storage space remaining on your MacBook. Free Some storage space and try again.

Answer (score 0):

Removing Xcode and reinstalling it again worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I met a similar issue, and I solved like below:
Click apple icon on the top left of screen > About this Mac > Storage > Manage > Developer and Open the screen, **delete all cache**, then it should work well.

[reference taken from](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/712008)

Comment: The reference you link in turn references a [stack overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72238810/20287183). Also note that this answer you have posted is out of date and doesn't apply as of macOS 13.

Comment: i got my issue resolved today, I'm on macOS 13.4.

Comment: That's great your issue is resolved. But you missed my point. The answer you gave doesn't apply to macOS 13+. There is no "Storage" option from "About this Mac" any more. You need to go to System Settings -> General -> Storage -> Developer.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting this error working with React Native. For some reason xcode built-in ruby needs sqlite3 when I try to distribute my app (exporting an IPA file). But when I ran `sudo gem install sqlite3` I got a ruby version compatibility error. Here's how I fixed it:

1. Using the default ruby, run `ruby --version` and it will output something like this

```
ruby 2.6.10p210 (2022-04-12 revision 67958) [universal.x86_64-darwin22]
```

2. Look at the value inside the `[` `]`. That is the platform for your local machine. In my case it's `universal.x86_64-darwin22`
3. Install `sqlite3` for this specific platform by running

```
sudo gem install sqlite3 --platform universal.x86_64-darwin22
```

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Running

`brew install sqlite 3`

and then restartarting XCode worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

"I successfully addressed the bug by optimizing storage space on my MacBook."

Answer (score -1):

for me it was because of low storage. I deleted unnecessary things and restarted the Xcode.then after having enough space, it worked for me