# Xcode Simulator: Cannot Create Simulator?

Tags: xcode, macos, simulator

I've used the Xcode Simulator many times. But for some reason now (possibly related to the recent OS-X update?) it's not working on my system.

The "OS Version" dropdown is empty and has nothing to select.

The "Create" button is enabled but when I click it nothing happens.

I've followed the instructions on this [SO Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72229589/flutter-xcode-error-unable-to-boot-the-simulator):

- Deleted the Mac Storage Management->Developer data
- Deleted Xcode from my computer, emptied the trash, and reinstalled Xcode from the OS-X App Store

..but the anomaly is still present.

How can I fix this?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you forgot to install the new iOS 17 SDK. This is a separate download from Xcode itself, and is not the same as the previous SDK. Go to Xcode's Preferences -> Platforms and perform the download.